# Getallvisibleitems() returning product not visible in catalog/search

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to get order item id by going over all items present in the order with getAllItems(). The problem is I am getting only the simple product even though the product has a parent item (double checked with $item->getParentItemId()) and is not visible individually. Even when I try getAllVisibleItems() I only get the simple product. In admin panel, I can see that only the configurable product, which I am not getting, is visible and none of its simple products are.

Also, is it possible to have a simple product which is visible individually and also associated with a grouped/configurable product? This is unrelated to the rest of the post but I will appreciate any help here as well. Thank you.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) 
{
    $k++;
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
    $product     = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    Mage::log($k.")".$product->getTypeId()." and id is ".$item->getId(), null, "MODB.log");
    if( $product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ){

        if ($item->getData('row_total_incl_tax') != null){
        $price = $item->getData('row_total_incl_tax');
        }

    if (!$item->getParentItemId){ //get simple prods data;}
    else{//get parent prods data;}.......
```

Answer (score 0):

I think getAllVisibleItems doesn't means "Visible in catalog"

```
public function getAllVisibleItems()
{
    $items = array();
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
       if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
          $items[] = $item;
      }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

^ If product is not deleted:
!$item->isDeleted() 
&& 
have no parent products (for configurable products):
!$item->getParentItemId()
so it is visible.

Try to add visibility filter to collection

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
```

Comment: Yup I see that. In fact I used getParentItemId() after looking at this function. But I am getting only a simple product when it does have a parent item(the configurable product). And I never get the parent item.